# Markup text above crescendo

Tags: lilypond

[image]

How do I position the markup text above the crescendo?

```
\relative c {
        c4\< c c c-\markup{ "sim." } | c c c c\ff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to to it is to change the outside-staff-priority.  A DynamicLineSpanner (the hairpin) has an outside-staff-priority of 250 so setting the TextScript (markup text) to anything below that will make the text appear above the hairpin.

```
\version "2.24.3"

\relative c {
        \override TextScript.outside-staff-priority = 200
        c4\< c c c-\markup{ "sim." } | c c c c\ff
}
```